# How do I shorten this load jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm pretty good with jQuery but when I get to stuff like this I need a little help.

So I want to shorten this code:

```
$(function() {
$('#experience_nav').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrap').load('files.html #content_experience', function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
        $('#content_experience').siblings().fadeOut();
    });

    return false;
});
$('#aboutme_nav').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrap').load('files.html #content_aboutme', function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
        $('#content_aboutme').siblings().fadeOut();
    });

    return false;
});
$('#recentclients_nav').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrap').load('files.html #content_recentclients', function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
        $('#content_recentclients').siblings().fadeOut();
    });

    return false;
});
$('#contactme_nav').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrap').load('files.html #content_contactme', function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
        $('#content_contactme').siblings().fadeOut();
    });

    return false;
});

});
```

So that I don't have to basically keep calling the same thing for each different instance.

Any Help at all is great! Even just telling me it can't be done! :-)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that helped you the most! (by clicking the gray tick below the votes.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// All <a>s wich the ID ends with '_nav'
$('a[id$="_nav"]').click(function() {
    var nav = $(this).attr('id').replace('_nav', '');

    $('#contentWrap').load('files.html #content_' + nav, function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
        $('#content_' + nav).siblings().fadeOut();
    });

    return false;
})
```

Comment: To make it more lightweight in this case: `$('a[id$="_nav"]').live('click',function(){`....

Comment: @Nick Craver - If you don't need to use the live() why use the live()?

Comment: Live listens at a higher level (DOM root) rather than analyzing every element and hooking up duplicates of the same event handler, it's recommended when using the same event handler multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, taking advantage of your naming scheme:

```
$('#experience_nav, #aboutme_nav, #recentclients_nav, #contactme_nav').click(function() {
    var id = '#content_' + $(this).attr('id').replace("_nav","");
    $('#contentWrap').load('files.html ' + id, function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
        $(id).siblings().fadeOut();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively, as lightweight as possible since it's hooked up multiple times:

```
$('[id$=_nav]').live('click', function() {
    var id = '#content_' + $(this).attr('id').replace("_nav","");
    $('#contentWrap').load('files.html ' + id, function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
        $(id).siblings().fadeOut();
    });
    return false;
});
```